# Would anyone be able to help me interpret the dendrogram in the picture?

Tags: clustering, multivariate-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

[image]

The dendrogram was obtained using SPSS, the Nearest Neighbor method alongside the Squared Euclidian Distance. It groups together glass fragments from 3 different origins but I have difficulties with the number of clusters, can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you give us some more context by editing your post to clarify what variables you have and what sort they are? When you say 3 different origins do you mean you expected to get those three as your clusters?

Answer (score 1):

A dendrogram that looks like this indicates essentially that **the clustering failed**. Well, of course the algorithm did not fail (or you wouldn't have a result), but **there are no well-defined clusters**.

Your main problem is the lack of contrast. Many observations have distance 1. This is probably because you used categorical data?

Try other parameters & try to get better data, with continuous variables.

Comment: Why the downvote? The dendrogram *does* indicate the clustering has failed. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but **don't shoot the messenger**.

Comment: I agree there shouldn't be a downvote, but I do find myself wishing for some explanation of what you see in this graphic that leads you to your negative conclusion.  Why wouldn't the objects at the bottom constitute a few smaller clusters outside a single large cluster?

Comment: @whuber with your edit of the question, the image has become unreadable. As for the plot, I would rather say these are 7-10 outliers, and one "cluster" with the remainder of the data.